# Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: python, json

I've just started to learn programming in Python and I'm trying to make a Login System which uses the terminal and stores data into a JSON file and retrieve it to log in.

This is the part that looks is causing the problem.

```
def login():
    login_username = input("Enter your username: ")
    login_password = input("Enter your pass: ")
    with open("data.json", 'r+') as data:
        if login_username == username and login_password == password:
            print("Successful Login")
        else:
            print("Please Try Again")
            login()
```

When I am asked for the user and pass and the input matches the data from the JSON it will loop and ask to enter the username and password, again and again.

My whole code is below

```
import json

uname = ""
password =""


def register():
    uname = input("Enter a user to log in with: ")
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
    confirmed_pass = input("Enter the above password again")
    if password != confirmed_pass:
        print("Both the passwords does not match please re-enter a pass")
        password = input("Enter a password:")
        confirmed_pass = input("Enter the above password again")
    login_info = {
        "Username": uname,
        "Password": password
    }
    with open("data.json", "w") as write_file:
        json.dump(login_info, write_file, separators=(',', ':'))
    log = input("Would you like to login? (Y/N)")
    if log == 'Y' or log == "y":
        login()
    else:
        quit()




def login():
    login_uname = input("Enter your username: ")
    login_password = input("Enter your pass: ")
    with open("data.json", 'r') as data:
        if login_uname == uname and login_password == password:
            print("Successful Login")
        else:
            print("Please Try Again")
            login()


reg = input("Have you registered (Y/N) ?:  ")

if reg == 'Y' or reg == 'y':
    login()
elif reg == 'N' or reg == 'n':
    register()
else:
    print("Error!")
```

Comment: Can u show ur JSON file

Comment: Welcome to SO @jobin-raj-s. Have a look at how to ask questions -> [mcve]. What are you trying to achieve, what problems are you facing?

Comment: Where do `username` and `password` come from?

Comment: @skaul05 the json file is a empty file which just stores the data once we input the values in it.

Comment: @AndyK As I've stated it is a basic Login System via the terminal and I would like to input the values of User and pass and it would store it to the JSON file and login by retrieving the values from the JSON file and verifying it. 
Currently the input part is working alright but the login part is not , even though I input the same user and pass it still loops and asks us to try again.

Comment: @KlausD It's from the above function called register() . I've also given a link to the full code

Comment: @JobinRajS what the errors that you have in your login part?

Comment: @AndyK When I am asked for the user and pass and the input matches the data from the JSON it will loop and ask to enter the username and password. 

Ideally I would want it to just print out the message "Successful Login" but for some reason it does not work that way. I'm not sure if the way I implemented the JSON file method is correct either.

Comment: @JobinRajS I've amended your question the way I understood it with the details you've provided. Please feel free to amend the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you should first use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to load data in to a python dictionary:

```py
with open("data.json", 'r') as data:
    login = json.loads(data.read())
    # then you can use it like this
    if login_username == login['Username'] and login_password == login['Password']:
        ... Rest of the code
```

Just a heads your login will only work for last registered user, you should fix that.

Comment: Will it not be able to check the entire JSON file to see if the user has been registered or not? 
I'll check it out

Comment: open("data.json", 'w')  You are overwriting each time

Comment: I see. So I have to not overwrite but just add the data that I'm storing to the json file right ?

Comment: You will have to look into json array and python lists for that

Comment: @JobinRajS please think about accepting the answer if it solves the problem you raised. Cheers.

Comment: @andyK alright mate , already did. Kind of new to StackOverflow So I don't really know what to do but thanks for the help :D Cheers